# ¿Cómo evitar que el texto de un parrafo se salga de su div contenedor en HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Si tengo un `<div>` con un alto de `200px` y dentro un `<p>` con un texto demasiado largo, ¿ Cómo podría limitar el texto del párrafo para que no se pase del alto del `div`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes gestionar con los distintos valores de la propiedad css `overflow-y`.

En este ejemplo el primer párrafo únicamente muestra el texto que cabe en los 200px, mientras que el segundo muestra un scroll para poder visualizar el resto del texto:

```css
div{
  height: 200px;
}

.oculto{
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.scroll{
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="oculto">
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sed nulla maximus, lacinia quam vitae, efficitur erat. Etiam quis sagittis massa. Suspendisse eget nisi accumsan, egestas purus ac, malesuada orci. Quisque aliquet velit ut ipsum condimentum maximus. Curabitur ante nisi, aliquet a imperdiet vitae, dictum porta ex. Integer leo dolor, tincidunt ac felis consequat, elementum efficitur diam. Nullam dapibus tellus sit amet velit cursus tincidunt. Sed gravida aliquet risus. Fusce dictum elit eu lobortis cursus. Sed sodales quam dui. Pellentesque aliquam sed ex accumsan rhoncus. Nunc suscipit gravida dolor, sit amet rutrum lectus semper ac. Fusce gravida tincidunt ornare. Morbi a eros ipsum. Sed non enim sem.

Quisque felis ex, laoreet in nisl et, aliquam viverra erat. Integer efficitur porta tortor, ac laoreet risus tristique et. Sed ac massa nec arcu rhoncus commodo at non lorem. Pellentesque ac est efficitur, tincidunt velit eget, euismod enim. Donec accumsan mi nec massa ornare feugiat. Phasellus quis consequat dolor, ut auctor justo. Quisque volutpat viverra consectetur. Quisque neque tortor, convallis ut pulvinar id, vestibulum vitae nulla. Etiam at semper ipsum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Fusce in nisi vitae felis hendrerit molestie et sit amet magna. Nulla eget nibh eu nibh posuere volutpat. Mauris facilisis nec libero et elementum. Nunc rhoncus ut massa non bibendum.

Ut sollicitudin orci eu eleifend dictum. Cras gravida tempor ex nec ornare. Ut gravida mattis arcu, tincidunt pretium metus pharetra in. Sed ac lacinia velit, at pretium sapien. Ut placerat vestibulum libero, eu vestibulum orci volutpat a. Maecenas a laoreet urna. Mauris finibus urna at sem auctor, sit amet consectetur quam finibus. Nam lacinia, enim quis consequat euismod, est elit aliquam nulla, sit amet pulvinar mi magna at turpis.

Aliquam a nunc ut risus pellentesque eleifend. Cras varius justo in mi vehicula tempor. Quisque ultrices dignissim arcu, eget consectetur urna mollis quis. Vivamus congue urna orci, aliquet tristique urna molestie ut. Donec consectetur felis in quam suscipit viverra sed ut massa. Nullam euismod posuere magna. Nullam feugiat risus quis turpis suscipit, eget vestibulum ante bibendum. Sed consectetur euismod orci quis porta. Integer vitae sem venenatis, maximus diam a, laoreet elit. Quisque mauris est, aliquam nec mauris ac, auctor tempus arcu. Proin sit amet elit sollicitudin, interdum ligula at, congue felis. Donec condimentum, dolor ac iaculis auctor, enim sem porta lectus, id ornare risus augue vel ex. Nunc ut dapibus neque. Donec molestie ac tortor vel hendrerit. Donec venenatis felis nisl, in fermentum nunc blandit efficitur. Maecenas purus ligula, tempus sit amet sodales sed, egestas at erat.

Etiam posuere ex quis risus dignissim volutpat. Proin augue risus, venenatis in urna at, viverra gravida justo. Sed iaculis quam euismod commodo commodo. Integer at pulvinar diam, et viverra ante. Morbi mattis efficitur arcu, ac congue quam bibendum consequat. Integer a ante semper, facilisis lectus vel, elementum sapien. Nulla eget dolor ut ipsum condimentum gravida. Vivamus sodales urna a mauris ornare lacinia. Curabitur nec libero fringilla, malesuada sem elementum, commodo dui. Morbi sagittis, lacus auctor ultrices iaculis, lacus nisi rhoncus augue, vel scelerisque justo massa eu orci. Phasellus mattis ante leo, quis accumsan tortor hendrerit eu. Morbi ligula eros, commodo vel metus et, lacinia maximus felis. Morbi accumsan eros sed facilisis pellentesque. Cras eget elementum libero. Pellentesque pretium lacus eu ante vestibulum, ullamcorper elementum velit maximus.
</p>
</div>

<div class="scroll">
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sed nulla maximus, lacinia quam vitae, efficitur erat. Etiam quis sagittis massa. Suspendisse eget nisi accumsan, egestas purus ac, malesuada orci. Quisque aliquet velit ut ipsum condimentum maximus. Curabitur ante nisi, aliquet a imperdiet vitae, dictum porta ex. Integer leo dolor, tincidunt ac felis consequat, elementum efficitur diam. Nullam dapibus tellus sit amet velit cursus tincidunt. Sed gravida aliquet risus. Fusce dictum elit eu lobortis cursus. Sed sodales quam dui. Pellentesque aliquam sed ex accumsan rhoncus. Nunc suscipit gravida dolor, sit amet rutrum lectus semper ac. Fusce gravida tincidunt ornare. Morbi a eros ipsum. Sed non enim sem.

Quisque felis ex, laoreet in nisl et, aliquam viverra erat. Integer efficitur porta tortor, ac laoreet risus tristique et. Sed ac massa nec arcu rhoncus commodo at non lorem. Pellentesque ac est efficitur, tincidunt velit eget, euismod enim. Donec accumsan mi nec massa ornare feugiat. Phasellus quis consequat dolor, ut auctor justo. Quisque volutpat viverra consectetur. Quisque neque tortor, convallis ut pulvinar id, vestibulum vitae nulla. Etiam at semper ipsum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Fusce in nisi vitae felis hendrerit molestie et sit amet magna. Nulla eget nibh eu nibh posuere volutpat. Mauris facilisis nec libero et elementum. Nunc rhoncus ut massa non bibendum.

Ut sollicitudin orci eu eleifend dictum. Cras gravida tempor ex nec ornare. Ut gravida mattis arcu, tincidunt pretium metus pharetra in. Sed ac lacinia velit, at pretium sapien. Ut placerat vestibulum libero, eu vestibulum orci volutpat a. Maecenas a laoreet urna. Mauris finibus urna at sem auctor, sit amet consectetur quam finibus. Nam lacinia, enim quis consequat euismod, est elit aliquam nulla, sit amet pulvinar mi magna at turpis.

Aliquam a nunc ut risus pellentesque eleifend. Cras varius justo in mi vehicula tempor. Quisque ultrices dignissim arcu, eget consectetur urna mollis quis. Vivamus congue urna orci, aliquet tristique urna molestie ut. Donec consectetur felis in quam suscipit viverra sed ut massa. Nullam euismod posuere magna. Nullam feugiat risus quis turpis suscipit, eget vestibulum ante bibendum. Sed consectetur euismod orci quis porta. Integer vitae sem venenatis, maximus diam a, laoreet elit. Quisque mauris est, aliquam nec mauris ac, auctor tempus arcu. Proin sit amet elit sollicitudin, interdum ligula at, congue felis. Donec condimentum, dolor ac iaculis auctor, enim sem porta lectus, id ornare risus augue vel ex. Nunc ut dapibus neque. Donec molestie ac tortor vel hendrerit. Donec venenatis felis nisl, in fermentum nunc blandit efficitur. Maecenas purus ligula, tempus sit amet sodales sed, egestas at erat.

Etiam posuere ex quis risus dignissim volutpat. Proin augue risus, venenatis in urna at, viverra gravida justo. Sed iaculis quam euismod commodo commodo. Integer at pulvinar diam, et viverra ante. Morbi mattis efficitur arcu, ac congue quam bibendum consequat. Integer a ante semper, facilisis lectus vel, elementum sapien. Nulla eget dolor ut ipsum condimentum gravida. Vivamus sodales urna a mauris ornare lacinia. Curabitur nec libero fringilla, malesuada sem elementum, commodo dui. Morbi sagittis, lacus auctor ultrices iaculis, lacus nisi rhoncus augue, vel scelerisque justo massa eu orci. Phasellus mattis ante leo, quis accumsan tortor hendrerit eu. Morbi ligula eros, commodo vel metus et, lacinia maximus felis. Morbi accumsan eros sed facilisis pellentesque. Cras eget elementum libero. Pellentesque pretium lacus eu ante vestibulum, ullamcorper elementum velit maximus.
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, era lo que necesitaba!